# Why sql job is not executed from installer?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-installer, installshield

I'm trying to start a `sql server` job using following command.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'Cube Initializer'
```

If a run it manually it works perfectly, but I run this command in the `INSTALLER`(InstallShield) tool and I received following log message.

> SQL Server Agent is not currently
>   running so it cannot be notified of this action

But the SQLServerAgent is running on my machine and I don't understand why I received this log error while the SQLServerAgent is running.

Comment: Perhaps make sure the connection to the database has authenticated first: https://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield19helplib/helplibrary/SQL-StoreMSIProps.htm.  Maybe enable verbose logging to check this (MSIEXEC /i [path to MSI] /l*v c:\temp\temp.log).  You'd need to provide more info on how it is all currently configured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MSDB database in recovery state? Check if this database in online.
- Hanged SQL Agent Service? Restart SQL Agent service and try again.
- Few SQL Server instances installed and the command sent to a wrong one?